# How to get the attributes selected Magento

Tags: magento, attributes

what I need is relatively simple ...
I need to get the attributes that have been selected in the product page.

Explaining better:
I have a configurable product and have two attribute, size and color. When I go to buy the product, I have the options to select the attributes, I have a button that will do some actions and need to get the attributes that are selected.

Comment: Not clear Please elaborate... Why you want attribute to be preselected user should select it

Comment: The User will make the procedures normally, but before adding the product to the cart it will click another button had performed a certain action, this action should I get the attributes he chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On change of the dropdown do a ajax call which would return from the selected value

This would get you all attribute option and value. Change it according to your requirement

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
```

Still not sure what you want to achieve

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear yet, but what I need is just pick the attributes that are selected ...

Comment: In configurable product you are not selecting attributes. You are selecting attribute options and their values. From the above code you would get all attribute option and values

Comment: Right, sorry if I was not being clear, I need to get the selected values​​, it is possible?

Comment: In this example you are gone, how can I get the data?

Comment: Please specify what type of data you want give example.. I would try the complete code then

Comment: Like to Get the Labels, which I really need to be that the User selected, but getting one is already possible to do what I need.